# I want to convert this string to json object in android?

Tags: android, json

the string is

```
"categories": {
    "1": {
        "Id": "4",
        "name": "hm\u00c3\u0080\u00c2\u00afI\u00c3\u0084",
        "0": {
            "Id": "250",
            "name": "bpsI"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "251",
            "name": "tIcfw"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "252",
            "name": "C\u00c2\u00b4y"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "253",
            "name": "C\u00c2\u00bdnt{Kj\u00c2\u00b3"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "254",
            "name": "hntZiw"
        },
        "5": {
            "Id": "255",
            "name": "{]hmkn"
        },
        "6": {
            "Id": "256",
            "name": "Ncaw"
        },
        "7": {
            "Id": "294",
            "name": "FUnt\u00c3\u00a4mdnb\u00c3\u00b0"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "Id": "257",
        "name": "Atkmkntbj\u00c2\u00b3"
    },
    "3": {
        "Id": "258",
        "name": "kv]ncnNz\u00c3\u00b0"
    },
    "4": {
        "Id": "259",
        "name": "tlm\u00c2\u00abv Uo\u00c3\u00b0kv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "308",
            "name": "t{Kmkdn"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "310",
            "name": "CeIvt{SmWnIvkv"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "311",
            "name": "a\u00c3\u00a4p\u00c3\u0085h"
        }
    },
    "5": {
        "Id": "260",
        "name": "hnt\mZw",
        "0": {
            "Id": "261",
            "name": "kn\na"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "262",
            "name": "Nm\\u00c3\u00b0"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "263",
            "name": "kvt]m\u00c3\u0080Svkv"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "264",
            "name": "ayqkn\u00c2\u00a1v"
        }
    },
    "6": {
        "Id": "265",
        "name": "kvs]jy\u00c3\u00b0kv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "266",
            "name": "hm\u00c2\u00a1v]b\u00c3\u00a4v"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "267",
            "name": "Fs\u00c3\u00a2 \mSv"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "268",
            "name": "A\phw"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "269",
            "name": "{]XnIcWw"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "270",
            "name": "{]XnI\u00c3\u0084"
        },
        "5": {
            "Id": "271",
            "name": "Ip\u00c3\u00b3mbva"
        },
        "6": {
            "Id": "272",
            "name": "]cnNbw"
        }
    },
    "7": {
        "Id": "273",
        "name": "tImfwkv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "274",
            "name": "Imgv\u00c2\u00a8I\u00c3\u0084"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "275",
            "name": "aWntSm\u00c2\u00a1v"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "276",
            "name": "bm{X"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "277",
            "name": "FUnt\u00c3\u00a4gvkv"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "295",
            "name": "Irjn]mTw"
        }
    },
    "8": {
        "Id": "278",
        "name": "Fgp\u00c2\u00afv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "279",
            "name": "kmlnXyw"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "280",
            "name": "Ie"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "281",
            "name": "lmkyw"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "282",
            "name": "Im\u00c3\u0080\u00c2\u00abq\u00c2\u00ac"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "283",
            "name": "^o\u00c2\u00a8\u00c3\u0080"
        },
        "5": {
            "Id": "284",
            "name": "Adnhv"
        }
    },
    "9": {
        "Id": "285",
        "name": "tNmtZym\u00c2\u00afcw",
        "0": {
            "Id": "286",
            "name": "C\u00c2\u00bdnt{Kj\u00c2\u00b3"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "287",
            "name": "km\u00c2\u00bc\u00c2\u00afnIw"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "288",
            "name": "A\u00c2\u00a1u\u00c3\u00afn\u00c2\u00a7v"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "289",
            "name": "\nbaw"
        }
    },
    "10": {
        "Id": "290",
        "name": "BiwkI\u00c3\u0084",
        "0": {
            "Id": "298",
            "name": "hnhml hm\u00c3\u0080jnIw"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "299",
            "name": "P\u00c3\u00b2Zn\w"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "300",
            "name": "skent{_j\u00c2\u00b3"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "301",
            "name": "a\u00c3\u00a4p\u00c3\u0085h"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "304",
            "name": "BZyIp\u00c3\u0080_m\"}},"11":{"Id":"291","name":"\u00c2\u00a2mknss^Uvkv","0":{"Id":"302","name":"dnb\u00c3\u00b0Ft\u00c3\u008c\u00c3\u00a4v"},"1":{"Id":"303","name":"hn\u00c3\u00b0\u00c2\u00b8\bv\u00c2\u00a1v"},"2":{"Id":"305","name":"Bhiyap\u00c3\u00afv"},"3":{"Id":"306","name":"D
        ]ImckvacW"},"4":{"Id":"307","name":"Ncahm\u00c3\u0080jnIw"},"5":{"Id":"312","name":"am{
            Sn-tam-Wnb\u00c3\u00b0"}}}}
```

Comment: i want to use bind the data in android using hash map

Comment: i use the same code in this site
http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

Comment: @Nithinlal : your json is not valid you can check here http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 4):

Give this string to the input parameter of JSONObject constructor.

```
String str="";//Give your json string here
JSONObject object= new JSONObject(str);
```

Note: to insert `"` use escape sequence, so add `"` by `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

If your String starts form this "{" Then put ur whole String in

```
  JSONObjectjb=new JSONObject(YourString);//it convert into json object
```

If your String starts form this "[" Then put ur whole String in:-

```
  JSONArray jr=new JSONArray(YourString); //it convert into jsonArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass your string as an input parameter to the JSONObject constructor.

```
String test="your json string";
JSONObject object= new JSONObject(test);
```

You can also use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
String test = "your json string";
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(test);
```

It's a free and open source JSON parsing library, works beautifully with Android and yes, It really is that easy!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool to validate your json string : http://jsonlint.com/

I think you are providing an invalid JSON string.

To convert a valid JSON string to JSON object, you can try something like;

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("your valid json string here");
```

Answer (score 0):

your json is not valid you can check here [jsonviewer.stack.hu](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu)

You have Problem with 10th element in JsonArray :

```
"10": {
        "Id": "290",
        "name": "BiwkI\u00c3\u0084",
        "0": {
            "Id": "298",
            "name": "hnhml hm\u00c3\u0080jnIw"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "299",
            "name": "P\u00c3\u00b2Zn\w"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "300",
            "name": "skent{_j\u00c2\u00b3"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "301",
            "name": "a\u00c3\u00a4p\u00c3\u0085h"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "304",
            "name": "BZyIp\u00c3\u0080_m/"
          }

    },
```

`"name": "BZyIp\u00c3\u0080_m/"` from this line if you remove last `"/"` then you String converted to JSONObject

```
JSONObject object= new JSONObject(str);
```

OR this is your full valid json String :

```
{"categories": {
    "1": {
        "Id": "4",
        "name": "hm\u00c3\u0080\u00c2\u00afI\u00c3\u0084",
        "0": {
            "Id": "250",
            "name": "bpsI"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "251",
            "name": "tIcfw"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "252",
            "name": "C\u00c2\u00b4y"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "253",
            "name": "C\u00c2\u00bdnt{Kj\u00c2\u00b3"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "254",
            "name": "hntZiw"
        },
        "5": {
            "Id": "255",
            "name": "{]hmkn"
        },
        "6": {
            "Id": "256",
            "name": "Ncaw"
        },
        "7": {
            "Id": "294",
            "name": "FUnt\u00c3\u00a4mdnb\u00c3\u00b0"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "Id": "257",
        "name": "Atkmkntbj\u00c2\u00b3"
    },
    "3": {
        "Id": "258",
        "name": "kv]ncnNz\u00c3\u00b0"
    },
    "4": {
        "Id": "259",
        "name": "tlm\u00c2\u00abv Uo\u00c3\u00b0kv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "308",
            "name": "t{Kmkdn"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "310",
            "name": "CeIvt{SmWnIvkv"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "311",
            "name": "a\u00c3\u00a4p\u00c3\u0085h"
        }
    },
    "5": {
        "Id": "260",
        "name": "hnt\mZw",
        "0": {
            "Id": "261",
            "name": "kn\na"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "262",
            "name": "Nm\\u00c3\u00b0"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "263",
            "name": "kvt]m\u00c3\u0080Svkv"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "264",
            "name": "ayqkn\u00c2\u00a1v"
        }
    },
    "6": {
        "Id": "265",
        "name": "kvs]jy\u00c3\u00b0kv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "266",
            "name": "hm\u00c2\u00a1v]b\u00c3\u00a4v"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "267",
            "name": "Fs\u00c3\u00a2 \mSv"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "268",
            "name": "A\phw"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "269",
            "name": "{]XnIcWw"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "270",
            "name": "{]XnI\u00c3\u0084"
        },
        "5": {
            "Id": "271",
            "name": "Ip\u00c3\u00b3mbva"
        },
        "6": {
            "Id": "272",
            "name": "]cnNbw"
        }
    },
    "7": {
        "Id": "273",
        "name": "tImfwkv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "274",
            "name": "Imgv\u00c2\u00a8I\u00c3\u0084"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "275",
            "name": "aWntSm\u00c2\u00a1v"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "276",
            "name": "bm{X"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "277",
            "name": "FUnt\u00c3\u00a4gvkv"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "295",
            "name": "Irjn]mTw"
        }
    },
    "8": {
        "Id": "278",
        "name": "Fgp\u00c2\u00afv",
        "0": {
            "Id": "279",
            "name": "kmlnXyw"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "280",
            "name": "Ie"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "281",
            "name": "lmkyw"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "282",
            "name": "Im\u00c3\u0080\u00c2\u00abq\u00c2\u00ac"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "283",
            "name": "^o\u00c2\u00a8\u00c3\u0080"
        },
        "5": {
            "Id": "284",
            "name": "Adnhv"
        }
    },
    "9": {
        "Id": "285",
        "name": "tNmtZym\u00c2\u00afcw",
        "0": {
            "Id": "286",
            "name": "C\u00c2\u00bdnt{Kj\u00c2\u00b3"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "287",
            "name": "km\u00c2\u00bc\u00c2\u00afnIw"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "288",
            "name": "A\u00c2\u00a1u\u00c3\u00afn\u00c2\u00a7v"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "289",
            "name": "\nbaw"
        }
    },
"10": {
        "Id": "290",
        "name": "BiwkI\u00c3\u0084",
        "0": {
            "Id": "298",
            "name": "hnhml hm\u00c3\u0080jnIw"
        },
        "1": {
            "Id": "299",
            "name": "P\u00c3\u00b2Zn\w"
        },
        "2": {
            "Id": "300",
            "name": "skent{_j\u00c2\u00b3"
        },
        "3": {
            "Id": "301",
            "name": "a\u00c3\u00a4p\u00c3\u0085h"
        },
        "4": {
            "Id": "304",
            "name": "BZyIp\u00c3\u0080_m"
          }

    },
"11":{"Id":"291","name":"\u00c2\u00a2mknss^Uvkv",
"0":{"Id":"302","name":"dnb\u00c3\u00b0Ft\u00c3\u008c\u00c3\u00a4v"},
"1":{"Id":"303","name":"hn\u00c3\u00b0\u00c2\u00b8\bv\u00c2\u00a1v"},
"2":{"Id":"305","name":"Bhiyap\u00c3\u00afv"},
"3":{"Id":"306","name":"D]ImckvacW"},
"4":{"Id":"307","name":"Ncahm\u00c3\u0080jnIw"},
"5":{"Id":"312","name":"am{Sn-tam-Wnb\u00c3\u00b0"}
},
}
}
```